# What should be my port number if I am using php database locally in my pc and using that api in flutter mobile application using physical mobile

Tags: php, flutter, api, server, port

I am currently fetching api from php database(Served locally in my pc) and sending get/post request from flutter mobile application using  url = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/login" , here I used port number 10.0.2.2 because  I am using virtual emulator and it works fine. My question is what should be my port number if I am using physical mobile device to run flutter mobile application(Not virtual emulator). How can I get that port number?

Comment: you mean port or host? 10.0.2.2 is host and 8080 is port

Comment: You have to use ifconfig for Linux and ipconfig for Windows to get your LAN IP Address. Additionally you will have to make the firewall rules to allow traffic on those IP.  On the above scenario your LAN Address could be http://192.168.1.101:8000/api/login

Comment: just try it again by using your pc's IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/login
```

The `10.0.2.2` host is how you access your `localhost` from the emulator. But for physical devices its `0.0.0.0`

You might also need to run the below command after connecting your device. (ADB tools must be installed)

```
adb reverse tcp:8000 tcp:8000
```

Comment: this was helpful , it worked finally  .  You saved  me  Harshana Rathnayaka , Thank you.